# How to merge three text files into three columns on screen

Tags: bash, shell, awk

How can I merge three text files into three columns on screen?

```
1   A   1
2   B   2
3   C   3
    D
    E
```

I tried...

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt | column -s $'\t' -t
```

...but I always get

```
1   A   1
2   B   2
3   C   3
D
E
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

line 1-2 of file1.txt

```
USB Device Class ID:
CdRom&Ven_ZALMAN&Prod__Virtual_CD-Rom&Rev_
```

line 1-2 of file2.txt

```
USB Instance ID:
______XX00000001&1
```

line 1-2 of file3.txt

```
Last updated (Subkey):
2015-01-12 15:08:45 UTC+0000
```

Comment: Doesn't `paste file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt` on its own, without piping into `column`, do what you want? I tried it quickly and it seems to. If not, what do the original files look like?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your input files, but paste works as intended.

```
$ paste <(seq 1 4) <(seq 10 17) <(seq 5 9)
1       10      5
2       11      6
3       12      7
4       13      8
        14      9
        15
        16
        17
```

Answer (score 0):

`:|paste -d '   ' file1 - file2 - file3 | column -ts "| "` combine many files as a table `column -t` and `-s` as a separator `"| "`  .

the output will be like that

```
1    A    1
2    B    2
3    C    3
     D    
     E
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 3 files or a few to deal with you can do this:

```
$ paste foo[12].txt | expand -t 45 | paste - foo3.txt | expand -t 12
USB Device Class ID:                         USB Instance ID:           Last updated (Subkey):
CdRom&Ven_ZALMAN&Prod__Virtual_CD-Rom&Rev_   ______XX00000001&1         2015-01-12 15:08:45 UTC+0000
                                             ______XY0000000182
$
```

You need to choose the tab expansions `45` and `12` depending upon maximum line widths in `foo1.txt` and `foo2.txt`.

Comment: Hm...it works with this sample lines, but when a line in one text file has another length it don't work anymore.

Comment: I tried paste -d'\t' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > out.csv

It works, but in my file4.txt is at the end of all lines one unprintable character then it crashes again. F**k

Comment: @user3022917 not sure what you mean, *when a line in one text file has another length it don't work*. I tried different length lines in all the files and it worked as long as the 45 and 12 were chosen large enough to handle maximum length lines. I don't know what `file4.txt` is, it's the first time you've mentioned it.